# How to get the selected value and set a default value in a list with EurekaForm Library / Swift

Tags: swift4, eureka-forms

I use `xCode 9`, `Swift 4` and "Eureka form library" for my project.

The situation :

I have form with a list and a button.

I need help with these `2` issues :

1. when click on button I want to print the selected value
2. I want to be able to set  for the list an element as a default selected value

My `code` :

```
import UIKit
import Eureka

class myPage: FormViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        createForm()
    }


    func createForm(){
        form
        +++ Section("Sample list ")
        form +++ SelectableSection<ListCheckRow<String>>("Continents", selectionType: .singleSelection(enableDeselection: false))

        let continents = ["Africa", "Antarctica", "Asia", "Australia", "Europe", "North America", "South America"]

        for element in continents {
            form.last! <<< ListCheckRow<String>(element){ listRow in
                listRow.title = element
                listRow.selectableValue = element
                listRow.value = nil
            }
        }

        form.last! <<< ButtonRow("Button1") {row in
            row.title = "Get List Value"
            row.onCellSelection{[unowned self] ButtonCellOf, row in

            print ("Selected List Value = ????????")
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For printing all the form value:

```
print(form.values())
```

This will print the dictionary for the all form `values` keyed by the row `tag`.

For this case it prints like this (`Australia` is selected):

> ["Asia": nil,
>    "Africa": nil,
>    "Antarctica": nil,
>    "Australia": Optional(
>    "Australia"), "Europe": nil,
>    "South America": nil,
>    "Button1": nil,
>    "North America": nil]

Eureka's `SelectableSection` also have `selectedRow()` (for multiple selection `selectedRows()`) methods.

So you can get selected values like this:

First just add tag to `SelectableSection` to a tag.

```
form +++ SelectableSection<ListCheckRow<String>>("Continents", selectionType: .singleSelection(enableDeselection: false)) { section in
   section.tag = "SelectableSection"
}
```

Now on the button selection

```
form <<< ButtonRow("Button1") { row in 
        .. // button setup
    }.onCellSelection { [unowned self] (cell, row) in
        if let section = self.form.section(by: "SelectableSection") as?
                               SelectableSection<ListCheckRow<String>> {
            print(section.selectedRow()?.value ?? "Nothing is selected") 
        }
    }
```

Now For Default value selection:

```
let defaultContinent = "Antarctica"
```

Now in Button's `onCellSelection`:

```
}.onCellSelection { [unowned self] (cell, row) in
    .. // printing the selected row as above
    if let row = self.form.row(by: defaultContinent) as? ListCheckRow<String> {
       row.selectableValue = defaultContinent 
       row.didSelect()
    }
}
```